# Navigate Slick Slider right after load

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to be able to directly navigate in this slider right after loading a page. Normally after each fresh load I have to select the slider by clicking on any image to be able to navigate. I think I need an auto select function for the active slide or something of this kind but I have no idea what is it.

https://codepen.io/Robocop/pen/BpbMKQ

HTML

```
<section class="top_slider">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                   <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                 <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
               <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.slider {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: auto!important;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(".top_slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want arrows or what?

Comment: When loading the page, I want to immediatly move in the slide.

Comment: For now when I load the page, I have to click on the slide first to be able to navigate.

Comment: Have you checked all the options of slider https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/? And didn't find what you need?

Comment: The closest I got is with focusOnSelect . Only then I have to press tab first to be able to navigate.